# algorithm for matching css duplicates

Tags: css, algorithm

I'm looking for a library that can extract common css properties and add a class to the elements instead (I want to do this programatically, this is generated html, and I want to optimize it further by removing extra bytes).  For instance I have a bunch of defined styles for elements:

```
#element1 {
    font-weight:bold;
    background-image:url("some_url");
}
#element2 {
    font-style:italic;
}
#element3 {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
    background-image:url("some_url");
}
#element4 {
    background-image:url("some_url");
}

............ (crapload of elements)
```

that gets folded into:

```
.bold {}
.italic {}
.backgroundimage {}
```

or even better:

```
.bold-and-italic {}
.italic-with-bg {}
etc etc
```

Is there a library out there that already does this?  If there isn't, I could just go through and refcount all the properties, but is there a more optimal algorithm here?  It would be simple to do one property per folded class, but I believe it would get more complicated doing one class with multiple properties ... What kind of data structure should be used here?

Comment: I smell set covers, maybe a prefix tree in combination with viterbi and cutting it into pieces.

Comment: How would having `.bold {}`, `.italic {}` and `.backgroundimage {}` save bytes? Wouldn't you have a similar number of inline class declarations in the HTML file to replace those CSS lines? I can see how classes with more than one property might cut file length.

Comment: Well that's less important than the engineering problem itself.  As far as byte savings, it's small at best.

Comment: Have you tried parsing the rules using something like css-parse: https://github.com/reworkcss/css

Comment: What environment do you have on server-side? ASP.NET, PHP, can you execute Python, are there time-limits (how much time is between HTML generation and its serving?), what are the limitations on client-side? Details and limits please.

Answer (score 2):

I would look into [Sass](http://sass-lang.com) or [Less](http://lesscss.org). These are both great tools for what you're looking for. If you use either one of these, you need to have a Less/Sass compiler, so I would recommend [Prepros](http://alphapixels.com/prepros/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [CSSCSS](https://github.com/zmoazeni/csscss) a "CSS Redundancy Analyzer that analyzes redundant CSS" (heh) — I can't help you with the algorithm or implementation itself, but what you want to do sounds a a lot like one of the things detected by this tool.

The report output will give you a list of selectors that share common rules, so it could perhaps be used as a basis to generate the new rules you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look [CSSO](http://bem.info/tools/optimizers/csso/description/) optimization tool, concretely  http://bem.info/tools/optimizers/csso/description/#1-2-6--Partial-splitting-of-blocks

Example(from docs):

Before:

```
.test0 {
    color: red;
    border: none;
    margin: 0
}

.test1 {
    color: green;
    border: none;
    margin: 0
}
```

After:

```
.test0 {
    color: red
}

.test0, .test1 {
    border: none;
    margin: 0
}

.test1 {
    color: green
}
```